# Can bad DNS replication cause a user to loose connectivity to a shared drive

Tags: domain-name-system, replication, connection, share

We have multiple users that loose connections to shared drives on a particular server. I am able to ping the server hosting the files but can not see the host, or directories. Also its not 1 user, its almost all users accessing the particular drive at that particular time.

Comment: Define `bad DNS replication`.

Comment: According to the senior admin here there is replication issues were ipv6 and ipv4 servers are not communicating properly. That some servers decide to take only ipv6 and others decide to take only ipv4 replication. At least that is how am told, I'm pretty green so sorry if im not explaining correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, what they've told you makes no sense, at least not in the way you've conveyed it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the record is changed to a different value than it used to be and the users' cache is not refreshed, I doubt it. All the users encountering this issue at the same moment does not seem to be related to the DNS to me.
If your DNS server is not the same as the one that is not accessible you could look into the logs and see if something interesting is indicated.
Setting up a small cron job to regularly ping the IP and the hostname might be nice to completely exclude the DNS (and maybe manually adding it to the hosts file later on to see if there are differences).